Json object deserialization problem - property can have nested json object, but the serializer throws an exception
(.NET Framework 4.7.2) I am querying data from a web API and using the Newtonsoft JSON package for deserialization. The API returns an array of time/value pairs. My code works when the 'value' is straight forward numeric value. And my code works for all kinds of other objects that can be queried from the API. However, this API can occasionally put in nested Json objects into the 'value' when there is no/bad data, or other conditions. Because of this, my class uses 'object' type for the 'Value' property as instructed by the API vendor.
In the below situation, I am getting an exception when it tried to deserialize the Json object with the nested json  'value' value:
"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Object' because the type requires a JSON primitive value"
I've captured the Json response and boiled it down to this in order to isolate the issue:
//This works
String fooNoShutdown = "{\"Items\":[{\"Timestamp\":\"2024-01-01T08:00:00Z\",\"Value\":111},{\"Timestamp\":\"2024-01-01T09:00:00Z\",\"Value\":222}]}";
Root<PiValue> fooClassWorking = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root<PiValue>>(fooNoShutdown);

//This does not
String fooWithShutdown = "{\"Items\":[{\"Timestamp\":\"2024-01-01T08:00:00Z\",\"Value\":31.200000762939453},{\"Timestamp\":\"2024 - 01 - 25T03: 30:00Z\",\"Value\":{\"Name\":\"Shutdown\",\"Value\":254,\"IsSystem\":true}}]}";
Root<PiValue> fooClassNotWorking = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root<PiValue>>(fooWithShutdown);

In the second json string, the second item in the array is the troublesome nested json value:  '{"Name":"Shutdown","Value":254,"IsSystem":true}'
The 'Root' and 'PIValue' classes are defined as follows:
public class Root<T>
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
}


[JsonObject]
public class PiValue 
{
    private DateTime _Timestamp = DateTime.MinValue;
    private object _Value = 0d;

    /// <summary>
    /// Always gets set to Local Time
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty]
    public DateTime Timestamp
    {
        get { return _Timestamp; }
        set
        {
            _Timestamp = value.ToLocalTime();
        }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set
        {
            if (_Value != value)
            {
                double val = 0;
                if (value is null)
                    _Value = Double.NaN;
                else if (Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val))
                    _Value = val;
                else //string, enumeration set, etc
                    _Value = Double.NaN;
            }
        }
    }
}

I've tried changing the 'Value' property type to 'string' to see if it would just put the nested json object as-is, but it yields a different parsing exception. And in the vendor forums someone copied and successfully ran this particular code I pasted here, using the same .NET version.

Your problem is the same as the one from C# Json Deserialize Dynamic Type, namely that you pre-initialized your object value to a primitive, here private object _Value = 0d;.  The solutions from the accepted answer work for you  as well, e.g. adding [JsonProperty(ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace)] to public object Value resolves the exception, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/bK4g2h.  Closing as a duplicate.
